# Only use value inserted if it has the right size

Tags: c

The objective of the code is if the user inserts a name bigger than X characters I request a new name, until he inserts a name with or less than X caracters. I have the fallowing code:

```
char * getName(){
    int size = 4;
    int i;
    char inserted[10];
    char name[4];
    while (size > 3){
        printf("Insert name, maximum 3 characters: ");
        fgets(inserted, 10, stdin);
        for (i=0; i<4; i++){
            if (inserted[i] == '\n'){
                size = 3;
            }
        }
    }
    sscanf(inserted,"%s", name); 
    return name;
}
```

But it seems it doesn't work.....i tried debug but can't find error. If you could give a hand it would be wonderful.

**EDIT:** I have edit the code, there was a mistake

**EDIT:** The problem is not if the value is returned or not, but is is the function stays in a infinite loop - doesn't seem to find if the word has the right length

Comment: change `'/n'`  to `'\n'`. `/` is not a escape character. also note : Address of a local variable is invalid upon exiting the function.

Comment: It seems to be escape the loop when it is the correct type in the current code.

Comment: Yup, is already working, thanks

Comment: `return name;` should be `return strdup(name);`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

You cannot return a local variable address [`name`] from a function. You need to allocate memory dynamically to be able to return the pointer. You can make use of `malloc()` like

```
char * name = NULL;
name = malloc(4);
```

Then, from `main()` you have to `free()` the memory once you're done using it.

---

Old Answer:

First of all, you have to change `char name[3];` to `char name[4];` to make space for terminating null.

In your code, change

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++){
    if (name[i] == "/n")
```

to

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++){
     if (inserted[i] == '\n')
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY right, but more serious issue is there. Addressing that first. :-)

Comment: Please see again the code, i made a mistake writting it (name instead of inserted as you mentioned....)

Comment: @luisdias right. Did you notice the other changes i suggested?

Comment: @luisdias revert `int size = 3;` to `int size = 4;`.

Comment: The problem is that the program never exists the while cycle, so, it is not finding if the word is smaller than X. Grateful

Comment: @luisdias it is `'\n'`, not `'/n'`

Comment: Yup XD....i'll try it again...still doesn't work...already searched web and it seems i can't find any answer to this problem. Grateful

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a string literal with a character. You should change `"\n"` to `'\n'` so that you're comparing characters instead.  You're also returning a pointer to a local variable. You should probably return memory allocated on the heap using malloc.

Comment: Didn't used the malloc, changed, as you mentioned, the "" to '' but the code still doesn't work. Is there any method to see if input has less than X characters? Grateful

Comment: If you get rid of the syntax errors - you're missing a semicolon now after printf and using a forward slash '/n' instead of a backslash '\n' it should work (the loop exiting bit - the local memory issue is still there).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for now i'm just worried about the exit of the loop. Already tried with '/n' and '\n' and the result is the same (infinite loop). Grateful

Comment: What input are you giving the program?

Comment: any input should work...I'm trying with as and asd (both should work)

Comment: I've tried it with the same input and it works (copied and pasted) - I return NULL and print name as a test. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Copy and paste the code from above into your editor. It's possible you might not have updated something.

Comment: @luisdias Are you running a rebuilding executable file?